# How to disable submit button when regEx did not match

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi all I have written following code:

```
    <form action="" onsubmit="validate()">
      <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" maxlength="20" name="CompanyName"/>
      <button>Continue</button>
    </form>    

    <script>
      function validate(){
        var company_Name = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input').value;
        var companyRGEX = /[2-9]{1}\d{3}/;
        var result = !companyRGEX.test(company_Name);
        alert(result)
      }
   </script>
```

I want to disable the button if the input does not match the regular expression, and enable it if it matches. How can I achieve to that result?

Comment: If you want to stop the form from submitting. Then use preventDefault(). If you want to validate on user input. Then add a listener to the change event and set the disabled attribute there.

Comment: html5 pattern attribute with required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript to dynamically disable the button, use the following:

1. The `input` eventListener to listen for changes in the field value;
2. The `.disabled` property to toggle it.

How I implemented on your solution:

1. Created two variables to hold references to the `field` and to the `button`.
2. Added `validate` as the function for an `input` eventListener (attached to the `field`).
3. Compared the `field.value` to the `companyRGEX` using `string.match(regEx)`.

You can run the snippet below.

```js
let companyNameField = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input');
let button = document.getElementById('ContinueButton_6');

companyNameField.addEventListener('input', validate);
    
function validate(){
    var companyNameValue = companyNameField.value;
    var companyRGEX = /[2-9]{1}\d{3}/;

    if(!companyNameValue.match(companyRGEX)) {
        button.disabled = true;
    } else {
        button.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="validate()">
    <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" maxlength="20" name="CompanyName"/>
    <button id="ContinueButton_6">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Np. By the way, if you are using this for some form of security validation, be sure to check again on the server side, since you can't trust the client to send safe input.

Answer (score 0):

Just use pattern with required. No JavaScript is needed

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="validate()">
  <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" maxlength="20" name="CompanyName" pattern="[2-9]{1}\d{3}" required>
  <button>Continue</button>
</form>
```

If you want to use JavaScript than cancel the submission

```js
function validateIt (evt) {
  var company_Name = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input').value;
  var companyRGEX = /[2-9]{1}\d{3}/;
  var isValid = !!companyRGEX.test(company_Name);
  if (!isValid) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert('error');
  }
}

console.log(document.querySelector("form"))
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", validateIt);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type=" text " id="FormField_6_input" maxlength="20" name="CompanyName" />
  <button>Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I know that I can resolve all with pattern but in my case I need js code

Answer (score 0):

add `addEventListener` to the input field the return a value from `validate` function

```js
document.getElementById('FormField_6_input').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = validate(this.value)
});

function validate(company_Name) {
  var companyRGEX = /[2-9]{1}\d{3}/;
  var result = !companyRGEX.test(company_Name);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="validate()">
  <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input" maxlength="20" name="CompanyName" />
  <button id="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```